# csv to database with special characters

Tags: php, database, wordpress, csv, unicode

I am working on fetching data from csv to database in wordpress .Below are my functions.The problem is it is not fetching special characters (e.g. Ā) properly.How can I modify this to make to fetch with special charecters.

```
public function process_feed(){

    // title, image URL, retail price, sale price, product link, SKU, group ID (new), inventory

    // CSV Fields
    // [id] => 00412504024374
    // [title] => D.L. & Co Votive Candle Gift Set-Multi
    // [description] => A collection of six 1 oz. votive candles in three scents: two Thorn Apple, two Angels Trumpet and two Lady Rhubarb candles. Each housed in signature hand-blown frosted glass vases. Delightfully packaged in signature silk hat box.
    // [google_product_category] => Home & Garden > Decor > Candles
    // [product_type] => Home > Decor & Accessories > Home Fragrance > Candles
    // [link] => http://www.barneyswarehouse.com/D.L.-&-Co-Votive-Candle-Gift-Set-125046857.html
    // [image_link] => http://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/Barneys/125046857
    // [additional_image_link] => 
    // [condition] => new
    // [availability] => in stock
    // [price] => 125.00 USD
    // [sale_price] => 45.00 USD
    // [sale_price_effective_date] => 2014-11-17T14:39:06/2015-11-17T14:39:06
    // [brand] => D.L. & Co
    // [gtin] => 
    // [mpn] => 00412504024374
    // [item_group_id] => 125046857
    // [color] => Multi
    // [material] => 
    // [pattern] => 
    // [size] => 1 Size
    // [gender] => Unisex
    // [age_group] => Adult
    // [adwords_labels] => 
    // [custom_label_0] => 
    // [custom_label_1] => 
    // [custom_label_2] => 
    // [custom_label_3] => 
    // [custom_label_4] => 

    $file_paths = array(
        get_option( 'sjr_product_import_file_path_1' ),
        get_option( 'sjr_product_import_file_path_2' )
    );

    if( !empty($file_paths) ){

        // Capture all product IDs in the feeds to compare against existing products in DB
        // to deactivate products that are no longer in the feeds.
        $current_products = array();

        foreach( $file_paths as $file_path ){

            $csv = new parseCSV();
            $csv->delimiter = "\t";
            $csv->enclosure = "";
            $csv->sort_by = "item_group_id";
            $csv->parse( $file_path );

            if( $csv->error === 0 ){

                $current_group = null;
                $i = $i_all = 1;

                foreach( $csv->data as $product_row ){

                    if( $current_group === $product_row['item_group_id'] ){
                        $i_all++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Only import one of the item group products
                    $current_group = $product_row['item_group_id'];

                    $i++;

                    $current_products[] = $product_row['id'];

                    $args = array(
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => $this->meta_field_prefix . 'product_id',
                                'value' => $product_row['id']
                            )
                        ),
                        'post_type' => 'imported_product',
                        'posts_per_page' => 1
                    );

                    $existing_post = new \WP_Query($args);

                    $post_data = array(
                        'post_title'     => $product_row['item_group_id'] . ' - ' . format_product_name( $product_row['title'] ),
                        'post_content'   => $product_row['description'],
                        'post_excerpt'   => $product_row['description'],
                        'post_status'    => 'publish',
                        'post_type'      => 'imported_product',
                        'post_author'    => 1,
                        'ping_status'    => 'closed',
                        'comment_status' => 'closed',
                    );

                    // No need for those items
                    $product_row['product_id'] = $product_row['id'];
                    unset($product_row['id'], $product_row['description']);

                    if( !empty($existing_post->posts[0]) ){
                        $post_id = $existing_post->posts[0]->ID;
                        $post_data['ID'] = $post_id;
                        wp_update_post($post_data);
                    } else {
                        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
                    }

                    // The rest are meta fields, add a prefix
                    if (isset($post_id) ){
                        $meta_fields = array(
                            'item_group_id' => $product_row['item_group_id'],
                            'product_name' => str_replace(strrchr($product_row['title'], '-'), '', $product_row['title']),
                            'product_id' => $product_row['product_id'],
                            'is_inactive' => 0,
                            'additional_information' => array(
                                'image_link' => $product_row['image_link'], 
                                'price' => $product_row['price'], 
                                'sale_price' => $product_row['sale_price'], 
                                'sale_price_effective_date' => $product_row['sale_price_effective_date'], 
                                'link' => $product_row['link'], 
                                'brand' => $product_row['brand']
                            ),
                        );
                        foreach( $meta_fields as $key => $value ){
                            if (is_array($value) ){
                                $value = serialize($value);
                            }
                            update_post_meta($post_id, $this->meta_field_prefix . $key, $value);
                        }
                    }

                } // end foreach

            } else { // else if( $csv->error === 0)

            } // end if( $csv->error === 0)

        } // end foreach( $file_paths as $file_path)
}
}

function format_product_name( $title ){
return str_replace( strrchr($title, '-'), '', $title );
};
```

DB :

```
function install(){

global $wpdb;

$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$db_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'products';

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $db_table (
          `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `row_id` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
          `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
          `description` text,
          `google_product_category` text,
          `product_type` text,
          `link` text,
          `image_link` text,
          `additional_image_link` text,
          `condition` text,
          `availability` text,
          `price` text,
          `sale_price` text,
          `sale_price_effective_date` text,
          `brand` text,
          `gtin` text,
          `mpn` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
          `item_group_id` int(22) DEFAULT NULL,
          `color` text,
          `material` text,
          `pattern` text,
          `size` text,
          `gender` text,
          `age_group` text,
          `adwords_labels` text,
          `custom_label_0` text,
          `custom_label_1` text,
          `custom_label_2` text,
          `custom_label_3` text,
          `custom_label_4` text,
          `feed_file` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          UNIQUE KEY `row_id` (`row_id`),
          KEY `title` (`title`),
          KEY `item_group_id` (`item_group_id`)
        ) $charset_collate;";

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

dbDelta( $sql );
} // End install ()
```

Comment: it's a character encoding problem, the csv and the database field have different character encoding.

Comment: so what can be done now

Comment: Uses PHPExcel library for reading any type of CSV and Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php php function iconv is a good option to handle encoding

Comment: ***"so what can be done now"*** , I guess the easiest way is to convert the csv text to the same character encoding of the database field before inserting the value. Use the php functions `utf8_encode` or `utf8_decode`. Do a coupe of tests and it will work.

Comment: any programing help to start would be more helpful .. i am blank

Comment: Does it happen with title, content or excerpt ?

Comment: now i found in title. but there can be chance of appearing in other filelds

Answer (score 0):

Try using your function `format_product_name` with utf8_encode/decode, i.e.:

```
function format_product_name( $title ){
$title = str_replace( "-", "", $title );
$title = utf8_encode( $title );
//you can also try $title = utf8_decode( $title );
return $title;
};
```

Then use it to format the post content:

```
...
'post_title'     => $product_row['item_group_id'] . ' - ' . format_product_name( $product_row['title'] ),
'post_content'   => format_product_name( $product_row['description'] ),
'post_excerpt'   => format_product_name( $product_row['description'] ),
...
```

---

Note:

Check your database **field** encoding setting to make sure it's **utf**, if not, you'll have to encode the csv content to match it, for that, use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or similar php function.

Comment: original has str_replace( strrchr($title, '-'), '', $title ); is the above str_replace works the same . just to clarify

Comment: You want to replace all `-` for `""` (nothing), right ?

Comment: if you need a `space` instead of `-` use: `$title = str_replace( "-", " ", $title );`. I've to go now, hope it works!

Comment: $title = str_replace( strrchr($title, '-'), '', $title ); this will not make any difference right.The reason is i dont want to make change to the eisting one only if that does not work ?

Comment: i have changed to utf .. what else i have to change?